# Redis Stream Producer Delivery Order

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce, spring-data-redis-reactive

I have `redis stream` producer and i have question about the order of records that producer sends to redis.

Redis clients use `TCP` to execute commands. https://redis.io/topics/protocol#networking-layer

The messages can be delivered out of order in `multiple TCP connections`. [The order of TCP message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887359/the-order-of-tcp-message)

Lets say that my producer executes command to publish `record-A` to redis, then it executes another command to publish `record-B`. I expect that `record-A` is *delivered before* `record-B`. But they could be delivered out of order by nature of TCP.

Is there any mechanism to support delivery order? I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive` (and `lettuce` client internally) as redis client.

Comment: Set the connection pool size to `1`. (Of course it will be a bottleneck in a multi-threaded environment.)

Comment: but it effects all applications that uses redis. i want the messages published by the same producer instance to be sequential. it makes more sense to handle this on the client side rather than on the redis server.

Comment: @sazzad i think you talk about spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active property. you are right